# numero feliz con python

Tags: python, python-3.x

7 es un número feliz, ya que:

7^2 = 49

4^2 + 9^2 = 97

9^2 + 7^2 = 130

1^2 + 3^2 + 02 = 10

1^2 + 0^2 = 1.

n no es feliz la suma de los cuadrados entrará en un bucle (de periodo 8):

4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4,...

````
for i in range(0,300):
    t=i
    a=i/100
    b=i/10-a**100
    c=i-b*10-a*100
    n=0
    while True:
        a=a**2
        b=b**2
        n=n+1
        t=a+b+c
        if t==1:
            print(n,":",i," es feliz!")
            l1.append(i)
            break
        if n>=50:
            print(i, "no es feliz!")
            l2.append(i)
            break
        a=t/100
        b=10-a*10
        c=t-b*10-a*100```
esto es lo mas cerca que estuve de lograrlo o eso creo pero no logro que t==1 haciendo que todos los números no sean felices!
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efectivamente te has dado cuenta del pequeño detalle que cuando un número no es feliz periódicamente la suma de los cuadrados se repite, por lo que caes en un ciclo infinito. El periodo no siempre es 8, puede ser 16 (6, 60, 112, 121, 176, ...).

Una solución muy simple es usar precisamente esto para romper el ciclo:

```
for numero in range(300):
    suma_cuadrados = set()
    while True:
        if numero == 1:
            print(f"¡{numero} es feliz!")
            break
        numero = sum(int(digito) ** 2 for digito in str(numero))
        if numero in suma_cuadrados:
            print(f"¡{numero} no es feliz!")
            break
        suma_cuadrados.add(numero)
```

O usando una función (Python >= 3.8):

```
def es_feliz(numero):
    sumas_cuadrados = set()
    suma_sqr = numero
    while (suma_sqr:= sum(int(dig) ** 2 for dig in str(suma_sqr))) != 1:
        if suma_sqr in sumas_cuadrados:
            return False
        sumas_cuadrados.add(suma_sqr)
    return True

for numero in range(300):
    if es_feliz(numero):
        print(f"¡{numero} es feliz!")
    else:
        print(f"¡{numero} no es feliz!")
```

Se hace uso de un conjunto, `suma_cuadrados` para ir almacenando las sumas de cuadrados previas, como sabemos que si el número no es feliz periódicamente tendremos una suma repetidas, basta con romper el ciclo cuando esto ocurra.

Comment: muchas gracias FJSevilla!

Answer (score 1):

**ACTUALIZACION**

Siguiendo los comentarios de FJSevilla, termine reescribiendolo como funcion

```py
def es_feliz(num):
    r = num
    suma_cuadrados = []
    while True:
        if r == 1:
            return True

        r = sum(int(x) ** 2 for x in str(r))
        if r in suma_cuadrados:
            return False

        suma_cuadrados.append(r)

for i in range(15):
    if es_feliz(i):
        print(f"{i} es feliz!")
    else:
        print(f"{i} no es feliz!")

# 0 no es feliz!
# 1 es feliz!
# 2 no es feliz!
# 3 no es feliz!
# 4 no es feliz!
# 5 no es feliz!
# 6 no es feliz!
# 7 es feliz!
# 8 no es feliz!
# 9 no es feliz!
# 10 es feliz!
# 11 no es feliz!
# 12 no es feliz!
# 13 es feliz!
# 14 no es feliz!
```

Comment: muchas gracias fcoventuraa!